# How to set a cookie based on a specific link being clicked

Tags: javascript, events

Using JS/jQuery, I want to set a cookie only when a user has clicked on a specific link.

The idea is to then target this cookie to prevent the link being shown again to the same user.

Please note I'm relativity new to this type of coding so my example may look terrible:

```js
$("#tert_wrapper").onClick(function setCookie(bodypos, yes) {
    document.cookie = bodypos + "=" + yes + ";path=/";
});
```

Cookie name is **bodypos** and the value assigned is **yes**. **#tert_wrapper** is the class of the link.

I'm struggling with the onClick event.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: the link is a

```html
<a href="...>
```

Comment: Is this a link like an `<a>` tag pointing to another page, or more like a button, keeping the user on the same page?

Comment: Updated the question - it's a link to an external site specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is the jQuery click event handler setup. Instead of `onClick`, which you would use in an HTML tag (`<a onClick="do JavaScript things">`), you want to use something like `$("#id").click(function() {});`.

See the [jQuery `click()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

A possible second issue is executing JS before navigating away from the current page. If the browser leaves your before executing your event handler, the cookie may not be set.

That stems from my general uneasiness about client-side code. A foolproof method would be to target `_blank` on your link so the page on your site remains open while the new site is loaded. If you'd prefer not to do that, your current event handler *should* work fine. I probably worry too much about browser behavior.

Comment: That's really useful, seems to have worked perfectly. The link actually opens a new window so the event handler should still execute on the site while the user is taken to the linked site.